# The argument type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I try to fetch data from firestore using for snapshot loop but got an error.

here's my code:

```
Future<List<Product>> getProducts() => _firestore
  .collection(collection)
  .where('show', isEqualTo: true)
  .get()
  .then((snap) {
List<Product> products = [];
for (int i = 0; i < snap.docs.length; i++) {
  products.add(Product.fromSnapshot(snap.docs[i]));
}
return products;
});
```

the error is at (snap.docs[i]].

Answer (score 1):

the recommended way is to use [FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/)

and a simple example for fetching data would be:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('products')
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
            print(doc["name"]);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `Product.fromSnapshot()` wants an `AsyncSnapshot` (Flutter class used by `StreamBuilder` and `FutureBuilder`) but you're giving it a `QueryDocumentSnapshot` which is a Firebase class. My guess here is you want to change the parameter type of that function.

Comment: I was just learning from following old video,
from what I understand he try to fetch all data from firestore and put it in an array.

Is that correct?

plus, the flutter code keep changing and deprecating old codes. It confuses me. hope you can help

Comment: It should be fine unless it's A LOT of data. Yes, a lot changed with Dart / Flutter / packages in a short time (for the better), so try to avoid older tutorials. You can learn a lot by reading Dart's [language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour).

Comment: I don't think it's a lot of data, since I just want to fetch picture and its data.
Btw i've updated the code to full code

Comment: What I meant by "change the parameter type of that function" is in your Product class, in the fromSnapshot function, change the type of the only parameter to QueryDocumentSnapshot. You might have to change things in the function's body as well.